# Multiple IF, ARRAYFORMULA, TEXTJOIN Returning FALSE

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, textjoin

I'm trying to show sizes available for unique products in one cell.
I currently have the following, however, it is returning FALSE in the cells that should be blank.

Returned value: XS,FALSE,FALSE,L,FALSE,FALSE,3XL,FALSE
Expected value: XS,L,3XL

`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$15>0,IF($A$2:$A$15=A2,$C$2:$C$15,""))))`

[Example Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jYn3.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expected results in rows 10-15 are not correct.

Try this formula

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",",1, 
   IF(($A$2:$A$15=A2)*($B$2:$B$15>0),$C$2:$C$15,"")))
```

[image]